# iOS UITextView recognize wrong link

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a textview in my cell. I have NSTimer that every 5 seconds changes a content of a cell. First time everything is ok. For example: This is test text find out on **www.example.com**. This is ok. But on timer I animate the cell and in my animation I'm changing the text of TwxtView. When this happens this is my text: **This is test text find out on www.example.com**. As you can see, it recognizes the whole text as url link and this is not good. I was looking for solution but could not find it, what's the catch? My TextView has property Editable set to NO and Scrollable set to NO, link detection is enabled.

Comment: Can you please post some code how you are detecting the links in UITextView

Comment: I use auto detection. I checked Detection Link in my attribute inspector.

Comment: Check Settings from this link once http://www.ioscorner.com/2014/06/detecting-links-in-uitextview-detecting.html

Comment: Everything is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem.
Clear link attribute before you set your content string.

Try this:

```
[self.yourTextView setAttributedText:[NSAttributedString new]];
[self.yourTextView setText:contentString];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have set `self.yourTextView.selectable = YES;` programmatically or from XIB.

Then you try below trick which work for me .

```
    self.yourTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.yourTextView setText:contentString]; // Set content in 5 secs here 
    self.yourTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It can not be scrollable. This is not working for me.

Comment: I have updated code , you may tried this , actually its not rendering properly when you set text dynamically. I was tried layoutIfNeeded but its not work

Comment: can you please share your code , then I will try to check what happen there.

Comment: I can not share a code, but in animation block I just set text property of a textView